# Set container port based on environment property

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am setting port value in an environment property while generating Pod yaml.

```
master $ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never --env=MY_PORT=8080 --dry-run -o yaml  > Pod.yaml
```

I am trying to use the environment property MY_PORT in the ports section of my Pod yaml.

```
spec:
     containers:
     - env:
       - name: MY_PORT
         value: "8080"
       image: nginx
       name: nginx
       ports:
       - containerPort: $(MY_PORT)
```

When i try to create the Pod i am getting following error message.

```
error: error validating "Pod.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort.containerPort: got "string", expected "integer"; if you choose to ignore theseerrors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I tried referencing like ${MY_PORT} , MY_PORT etc.. but all the time same error as above.

How i can use an environment variable value in an integer field.

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Arghya Sandhu No real life use case actually. I was trying this one as at times we can dynamically use some of the parameters from a configmap in our definition yaml , similarly i was trying to see if  i can able to dynamically pick the port value from environment property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an environment variable there.  In the [`ContainerPort` API object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#containerport-v1-core) the `containerPort` field is specified as an integer.  Variable substitution is only support in a couple of places, and where it does it is called out; see for example `args` and `command` in the higher-level [`Container` API object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core).

There's no reason to make this configurable.  In a Kubernetes environment the pod will have its own IP address, so there's no risk of conflict; if you want to use a different port number to connect, you can set up a service where *e.g.* port 80 on the service forwards to port 8080 in the pod.  (In plain Docker, you can do a similar thing with a `docker run -p 80:8080` option: you can always pick the external port even if the port number inside the container is fixed.)  I'd delete the environment variable setting.

Comment: "no reason to make this configurable." - I'd like to give you one: If you could define a variable for this and pass it down from top into the container, You'd be sure the ports do match (I assume the container would error out with a good description if you don't pass in the correct env variables). The way it is now, you tend to duplicate the port number again and again: 1 in the implementation of the service, 2 in the docker file (`EXPOSE`), 3 in the pod template `containerPort` and 4 in the service. Mistake is unlikely, but if, would be way more pain than the nice error the container gives.